# Django celery beat attributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'localize'

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I'm trying to get periodic tasks running with my Django project as per [this tutorial](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/celery-redis-django/).

When running celery beat with the command below:

```
celery -A proj beat -l info -S django
```

I get the following error:

```
celery beat v4.0.2 (latentcall) is starting.
    __    -    ... __   -        _
    LocalTime -> 2018-02-24 13:42:37
    Configuration ->
        . broker -> redis://localhost:6379//
        . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
        . scheduler -> django_celery_beat.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler
        . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
        . maxinterval -> 5.00 seconds (5s)
    [2018-02-24 13:42:37,244: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
    [2018-02-24 13:42:37,245: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
    [2018-02-24 13:42:37,255: CRITICAL/MainProcess] beat raised exception <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'localize'",)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "...lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/apps/beat.py", line 107, in start_scheduler
        service.start()
      File "...lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 528, in start
        humanize_seconds(self.scheduler.max_interval))
      File "...lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 44, in __get__
        value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
      File "...lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 572, in scheduler
        return self.get_scheduler()
      File "...lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 567, in get_scheduler
        lazy=lazy,
      File "...lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_celery_beat/schedulers.py", line 183, in __init__
        Scheduler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "...lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 204, in __init__
        self.setup_schedule()
      File "...lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_celery_beat/schedulers.py", line 191, in setup_schedule
        self.install_default_entries(self.schedule)
      File "...lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_celery_beat/schedulers.py", line 290, in schedule
        self._schedule = self.all_as_schedule()
      File "...lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_celery_beat/schedulers.py", line 199, in all_as_schedule
        s[model.name] = self.Entry(model, app=self.app)
      File "...lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_celery_beat/schedulers.py", line 88, in __init__
        model.last_run_at = self._default_now()
      File "...lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_celery_beat/schedulers.py", line 106, in _default_now
        return now.tzinfo.localize(now.replace(tzinfo=None))
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'localize'
```

Researching other StackOverflow posts suggests that an object is not being passed through somewhere which is causing the attribute error on a NoneType. I suspect the problem may have something to do with my nested local.py and production.py settings modules differing from what Celery may expect from a more typical settings module in the project app directory.

Below is my project structure and code. My virtualenv is enabled and all dependencies have been installed and are running. Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

**Directory structure:**

```
├── myproject
│   ├── myproject
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── base.py
│   │   │   ├── celery.py
│   │   │   ├── local.py
│   │   │   ├── production.py
│   ├── manage.py
```

**myproject/myproject/settings/__init__.py**

```
# myproject/myproject/settings/__init__.py

from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from .base import *

try:
    from .local import *
    live = False
except: 
    live = True

if live:
    from .production import *
```

**myproject/myproject/__init__.py**

```
# myproject/myproject/__init__.py

from __future__ import absolute_import

from myproject.settings.celery import app as celery_app
```

**celery.py**

```
# myproject/myproject/settings/celery.py

from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings.local')

app = Celery('myproject')

# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
  print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))



from celery.schedules import crontab
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'add-every-minute-crontab': {
        'task': 'fetch_news',
        'schedule': crontab()
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have some timezone defined in setting.py? (for CELERY_ and django) ?

Comment: Yes, CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE. TIME_ZONE = ‘UTC’ higher up in the local.py and production.py settings modules.

Comment: and time_zone is equal to what?

Comment: from where do you run the celery beat? are you using the corect projectname?

Comment: Sorry, posted comment accidentally before finishing. TIME_ZONE = ‘UTC’ higher up in the settings module.

Comment: I'm running it from the project root (folder that contains manage.py). Redis and Celery worker are running too. Yes, I'm substituting proj with my project name when running the command.

Comment: ok, i would try to fit the `__init__.py` to the format as in documentation http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html , also try to remove the crap you inserted there, but if it is relevant provide what those files contains... and maybe i would try to do absolute imports rather then relative

Comment: Corrected original post as the absolute import wasn't highlighted as code at the bottom of `myproject/myproject/__init__.py`. Have also added the `__all__ = ['celery_app']` as per Celery docs but hasn't changed anything. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully overcame the problem by adding in the settings:

```
DJANGO_CELERY_BEAT_TZ_AWARE=False
```

Then, I got an exception

```
kombu.exceptions.VersionMismatch: Redis transport requires redis-py versions
```

This was solved by https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5369#issuecomment-469302960

I also have also noticed that django-celery-beat version 1.1.0 don't have this specific issue, but it will **NOT** send signals using crontabs. So you shoud use a higher version.